# Updating CSS Values in Javascript across multiple elements in batch?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, reflow

I have a web app I'm working on that requires frequent updates to CSS values across multiple elements. I'm trying to reduce reflow and was wondering if there is a way to accomplish this in batch? Here's an example:

```
for(let j = 0; j<defholdids.length; j++) {
    $('#'+defholdids[j]).css({
      'z-index':'4',
      'color':'rgba(0,0,0,0.7)',
    });
```

`defholdids` is an array with the element ID's stored. The loop iterates through and updates the css values. To my understanding, a reflow is triggered each time an element css value is updated. Is there a way to update the CSS values across all the elements AND THEN 'reflow' rather than triggering a 'reflow' each iteration?

I'm working with Electron to create a desktop app, not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nearly always better off by introducing a (second) class then adding/toggling/removing that class on the appropriate element(s), instead of directly manipulating the `.css()` of elements.

In Joseph's answer he introduces `.class-name-goes-here` (which I'll shorten to `.main-class`
If you introduce a second/additional class:

```
.aux-class {
  z-index:4;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
```

you can do `$('.main-class').addClass('aux-class');`
This would apply the change to all of the `.main-class` elements all at once.

You can change it back later just by `$('.main-class').removeClass('aux-class');`

If you have well-known & well-maintained state you can use [`.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) instead of separate adds and removes.

This doesn't prevent you from doing further manipulations with `$(element).css()` but those changes would have to be reverted "manually". I would probably introduce *another* different (third? fourth?) class instead.

It's also good to name the class for the state (or object) it represents.
Those names depend on what the things are and what you're doing with them. Maybe instead of `.main-class` and `.aux-class` good names could be `.toggleable` and `.active`, so possibly

```
<section>
  <div class="toggleable">
    ...some content...
  </div>

  <div class="something-else">
    ...some other content...
  </div>

  <div class="toggleable">
    ...even more content...
  </div>

  <div>
    ...no particular class on this div...
  </div>
</section>
```

Then, on a button press (for example) you would do
`$('.toggleable').addClass('active')`

Comment: Thank you for the advice. If I know there are say only two states my element is in (color white with z-index 99 OR color black with z-index 4) would applying/removing the 'change' class to the element accomplish what I need? I could apply it specifically to the 'selected' elements, and then remove it from ALL elements? Does trying to remove a class that isn't bound to an element OK? Basically I have a button that needs to clear all, but allow users to select individual elements.

Comment: Also, if I misunderstood please correct me, but I read somewhere that applying CSS changes to the lowest possible element on the DOM tree saves reflow time, wouldn't this go against that?

Comment: If you know there are only 2 states, which one is the _default_ or _initial_ state? I would have no extra class on those, then have a "selected" class when the user selects things. Let's say we're talking about "cards", and the initial unselected state is white/z-index=99 — you would have all these `<div class="card">` and the CSS for `.card {...}` would apply white and 99, then when the user selects you would add `$(clickedElement).addClass('selected')` … you can do `$('.card').removeClass('selected')`for the clear button. `.removeClass` when a class isn't on an element if fine; not an error.

Comment: Not every CSS change causes reflow; colors don't. z-index might (I don't recall), but with this method you're still applying z-index to the lowest possible element, because the `.card` _is_ the thing you want to change in the stacking order. You wouldn't want to apply z-index to some element _within_ the card.

Comment: that's what I needed to know!

Answer (score 1):

How about assigning one class name for the elements that require cssupdates and update them at once. For example

```
   $('.class-name-goes-here').css({
      'z-index':'4',
      'color':'rgba(0,0,0,0.7)',
    });
```

Comment: Would that override/prevent changes to the css of an individual element via ID? Example: I need to be able to update say ```$('#'+defholdid[1]).css('color','value')``` without updating the class. Then later change it back (via the code I showed). Wouldn't the ID CSS value override the class value reset?